# Redirect for initial page works,but the next page shows the old url in the browser

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/page/%1/%1/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Compare/([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Compare/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$1&totalRows_RS_Search=$2&Category=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The redirect for the Category.php?Category=.. works fine, but when I want to go to the next page of this category so keeping ^Compare/Category name to the next page with this code gives me 
^Compare/page/1/1/1 and as a result the next page is looking for category 1, it should be looking for category category name. Is there a way to show:
^Compare/page/1/8/Category name?
The eight is just a number of the total rows the 1 is obviously the page number and the Category is the Category name. 
The next page is created with dreamweavers navigation bar using php.
Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your faulty very first rule where your are using `%1` again & again instead of `%2` and `%3`.

It should be this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^&]+)&Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/page/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have added another rule for the news page which works fine on the local server, however when I upload it to the main server it can't find the page. What am I doing wrong? RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+news\.php\?news_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=301,L]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?news_id=$1 [L,QSA]. Will start a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455539/htaccess-works-on-local-server-not-on-main-server this is the link

Comment: Sure let me check other question.