# .htaccess works on local server not on main server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file working on the local MAMP server fine. However when I upload it to the main server it can't find the news page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+news\.php\?news_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Compare/([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$1&totalRows_RS_Search=$2&Category=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?news_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The Category and product redirects work fine on the main server however the news doesn't gives a 404 error

other rewrite rules one level higher

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite1.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite1.co.uk$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L] #5311a623b538f
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk$
rewriterule ^Pianoshop\/detailed_page\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/product\.php$1" [R=301,L] #5310700a7e477
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk$
rewriterule ^Pianoshop\/index_blog\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.co\.uk\/news\.php$1" [R=301,L] #531
```

Comment: Have you **checked** that you have uploaded the `news` page on to the server? (In the _correct_ location)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked that and the links work fine when there is no redirect.

Comment: Okay, what URL is shown on the `404` error page?

Comment: the url is /mysite.co.uk/news/34-news-title

Comment: Is this the entire content of your `.htaccess` file? Are there any others on the server?

Comment: There are some more rules one level higher (webroot) my website is in a folder in which the .htaccess file is placed.

Comment: Can you show them too?

Comment: I'll admend the question so you can see the other rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is happening due to `MultiViews` option enabled on your live server which conflicts with `mod_rewrite.

Add this line on top of your .htaccess to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thanks you again it sorted the problem. I think I'll call you my super teacher

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it will be problem with apache configuration check your apache configuration

[Check This for more Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709893/htaccess-not-working-in-server)

Comment: thanks for your reply I think it is ok as the other rules work fine.